# Formula to include range.address only if it has been set

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to write a formula into a cell on my Excel worksheet.  The formula is written into the cell using the following code, where xWF1 through wWF5 are all single-cell ranges.

```
xWF1.Formula = "=" & xWF2.Address(True,True) & "-" & xWF3.Address(True,True) & "-" & xWF4.Address(True,True) & "-" & xWF5.Address(True,True)
```

xWF2 through xWF5 are set earlier in the code, if they exist.  When one of them doesn't exist, the line of code above errors.

What I would like, is for the code to write the formula to include only those ranges that exist.  For example, if xWF4 doesn't exist, the formula would be xWF2-xWF3-xWF5

What would be a better way to write this code?

Comment: Check if the objects are `Nothing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Test Ranges For `Nothing`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim xWF1 As Range, xWf2 As Range, xWf3 As Range, xWf4 As Range, xWf5 As Range
        
    Set xWF1 = Range("A1")
    'Set xWf2 = Range("A2")
    'Set xWf3 = Range("A3")
    'Set xWf4 = Range("A4")
    'Set xWf5 = Range("A5")
    
    ' The above is irrelevant for your code.
    
    Dim rArr As Variant: rArr = Array(xWf2, xWf3, xWf4, xWf5)
    Dim dFormula As String: dFormula = "="
    
    Dim rg As Variant
    
    For Each rg In rArr
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then dFormula = dFormula & rg.Address & "-"
    Next rg
    ' Remove the trailing '-', or the '=' if all four ranges are 'Nothing'.
    dFormula = Left(dFormula, Len(dFormula) - 1)
    
    xWF1.Formula = dFormula

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you follow @Ron_Rosenfeld's suggestion and trap for the various possibilities this one should work for you.

I don't check for xWF1

```
Public Sub TestMacro()

    Dim strxWF2     As String
    Dim strxWF3     As String
    Dim strxWF4     As String
    Dim strxWF5     As String
    
    Dim strFormula  As String
    
    If Not (xWF2 Is Nothing) Then strxWF2 = xWF2.Address(True, True)
    If Not (xWF3 Is Nothing) Then strxWF3 = xWF3.Address(True, True)
    If Not (xWF4 Is Nothing) Then strxWF4 = xWF4.Address(True, True)
    If Not (xWF5 Is Nothing) Then strxWF5 = xWF5.Address(True, True)
    
    If (strxWF2 <> "") Or (strxWF3 <> "") Or (strxWF4 <> "") Or (strxWF5 <> "") Then
        
        strFormula = "="
        If (strxWF2 <> "") Then strFormula = strFormula & strxWF2
        If (strxWF3 <> "") Then strFormula = strFormula & "-" & strxWF3
        If (strxWF4 <> "") Then strFormula = strFormula & "-" & strxWF4
        If (strxWF5 <> "") Then strFormula = strFormula & "-" & strxWF5
    
        xWF1.Formula = strFormula
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This solution looks great, though I ended up going with the Array solution.

Comment: No problem - glad you found a solution